# Make images (position:fixed) be visible only inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to create a website, inspired by http://cirkateater.no/en/ .
**The images shall stay at the same position on the Screen (position:fixed), but inside the next div, the second image shall be visible.**

My first solution was to use background-images, which worked.

With background-images, it looked like this JSFIDDLE: 
**http://jsfiddle.net/Ryanous/r7mLm4wg/4/** (*i do not own these images*)
Consider the following code:

```
<div class="background" style='background-image:url("http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg");'></div><div class="background" style='background-image:url("http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg");'></div>
```

**But I also want to move the images via JS later on!**
You cant manipulate backgroundimages top-offset easily, so I decided to use an img-tag instead.

Now, using the img-tag, the images seem to be independent of their divs, and overlap each other so that *always only one image is visible*.

( *id like to include my current code but stackoverflow wont let me do. four spaces dont do anything, i cant format my code.* )

**So my question is:




How can I make images be only visible inside a certain div, but keep their positions fixed?**

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle of your current code?  I'm going to try a few things.

Comment: Have you tried Overflow for Div? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: jsfiddle of current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ryanous/ddrwkstr/1/

Answer (score 2):

Putting the style `overflow:hidden;` on the div would hide all that's outside of the div.

Comment: By the way, the effect is called parallax scrolling.

Comment: thanks, that seems very obvious but i didnt try it yet    
oh, it doesn't work:
jsfiddle of current code: [link](jsfiddle.net/Ryanous/ddrwkstr/1)
I don't know why, id actually should.

Comment: @Johannes I don't exactly understand what you're willing to achieve, but I think it's due to `z-index`, you have to add `position:relative` to the div without fixed positioning.

Comment: the overflow, in this case, seems to not work because the position of the images is fixed. (It works if position is not fixed.)

Comment: i want to add many images, like you can see at http://cirkateater.no/en/
I dont want to create a new css-class for every image, is that possible?